# mariaDB insert into a join view issue

Tags: insert, view, mariadb

I am trying to insert/update an entry into a view which was created by joining more than 2 base tables. the issues I have is.

1. Is it even possible to update such a view using insert command or do
   I have to modify base tables individually?
2. It says you cannot insert without mentioned the field names when I
   use  insert command without field names.
3. One of the field label has a space, and I am not able to figure out
   the correct syntax for insert when I use field names, i have used
   single/double quotes an [], it still throws syntax errors.

Answer (score 0):

Is possible to insert new rows in a view but only on certain circumstances.

For more information, see: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/inserting-and-updating-with-views/